# I want to make an array of hashes from two value arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have two arrays. One array contains longitudes, the other array contains latitudes.

I need to create an array of hashes called markers. Each marker will have a key latitude and a corresponding value. It will also have a key longitude and a corresponding value. How do I create an array of hashes from the both arrays.

I am very stuck so any help would be greatly appreciated

My code is below

```
array_of_lon = [162.143815475374, 168.950878940823, 3.64965696346187, -167.21528146934, 177.219093253956]

array_of_lat = [7.07533432185069, -71.1633951653961, 83.684201546539, -41.7868611360175, 22.3943085903501]

array_of_markers_hashes = []
```

Comment: When asking, we need to see evidence of your effort to solve the problem. Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write code. SO isn't a "write code for me site", instead we help fix the code you wrote.

Answer (score 4):

Try this way

```
markers = array_of_lon.zip(array_of_lat).map do |lon, lat|
  { latitude: lat, longitude: lon }
end
 => [{:latitude=>7.07533432185069, :longitude=>162.143815475374}, {:latitude=>-71.1633951653961, :longitude=>168.950878940823}, {:latitude=>83.684201546539, :longitude=>3.64965696346187}, {:latitude=>-41.7868611360175, :longitude=>-167.21528146934}, {:latitude=>22.3943085903501, :longitude=>177.219093253956}]
```

Answer (score 2):

For a single pair of values, you'd use:

```
lon = 162.143815475374
lat = 7.07533432185069

{ lon: lon, lat: lat }
#=> {:lon=>162.143815475374, :lat=>7.07533432185069}
```

To combine the two arrays, there's [`zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-zip):

```
array_of_lon.zip(array_of_lat)
#=> [
#     [162.143815475374, 7.07533432185069],
#     [168.950878940823, -71.1633951653961],
#     [3.64965696346187, 83.684201546539],
#     [-167.21528146934, -41.7868611360175],
#     [177.219093253956, 22.3943085903501]
#   ]
```

And finally [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) to convert these pairs to markers:

```
array_of_lon.zip(array_of_lat).map do |lon, lat|
  { lon: lon, lat: lat }
end
#=> [
#     {:lon=>162.143815475374, :lat=>7.07533432185069},
#     {:lon=>168.950878940823, :lat=>-71.1633951653961},
#     {:lon=>3.64965696346187, :lat=>83.684201546539},
#     {:lon=>-167.21528146934, :lat=>-41.7868611360175},
#     {:lon=>177.219093253956, :lat=>22.3943085903501}
#   ]
```